# Register windows service through bitrock

Tags: windows

I am working on a windows service , i can register the windows service through command line , but that is not required, so my requirment to register the service through bitrock installer(i am using btrock installBuilder to make the release of the application)

if someone has any idea please share....

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683500(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanx for respone Abhineet , but i am asking about the way to register service  using bitrock installbuilder and i have written the service in C# 

so do you have any idea about bitrock installbuilder service instalation , i am not even sure it is possible through bitrock or not